# Failure in http request/response from GAS to own server

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I send a request from GAS to my server but fail to receive a response.

Error: Unexpected error: http://examle.com:9119

When I send the request to Google's server, I receive the response.

When I send the same request to my server with Postman, it succeeds.

I don't know how to solve this problem: 。。。。

GAS Code

```
function sendPostRequest(data) {
  // target server
  const url = 'http://examle.com:9119';
  
  const body = JSON.stringify({ title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1 });

  const options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': body,
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': '*/*',
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': false
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response.getHeaders()); // Log the response body
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ', error.message);
    console.error('Stack trace: ', error.stack);
  }
}
```

```
Error:  Unexpected error: http://examle.com:9119
```

MyServer

```
    private static void dataBack(@Nullable String result, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            if (result == null) {
                out.write(UnknownErrorMessage.getBytes());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                return;
            }

            out.write(result.getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.info("dataBack error: " + ex.getMessage());
            handleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

When I log to my server, the request is received.

If I wait 5 seconds before returning the response, GAS outputs an error after 5 seconds, so something seems to be wrong when GAS receives the response.

Comment: I would guess that you require an authorization header?

Comment: There was a miss-description of the http response header on my server.
Thank you very much.